# Server nvidia-smi GPU utilization always 0%

Tags: nvidia, gpu

I have search many times on Google, but I haven't found any related issues on NVIDIA and Stackoverflow.

`uname-a` output:

```
Linux k8s-node1 5.15.0-79-generic #86~20.04.2-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jul 17 23:27:17 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

`nvidia-smi` output:

```
Tue Dec 12 17:22:14 2023
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 515.65.01    Driver Version: 515.65.01    CUDA Version: 11.7     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce ...  Off  | 00000000:1E:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 30%   37C    P8    21W / 350W |  12297MiB / 24576MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  NVIDIA GeForce ...  Off  | 00000000:5E:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 30%   36C    P8    16W / 350W |      2MiB / 24576MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   2  NVIDIA GeForce ...  Off  | 00000000:AF:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 30%   39C    P8    24W / 350W |      0MiB / 24576MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   3  NVIDIA GeForce ...  Off  | 00000000:D9:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 36%   39C    P8    24W / 350W |  12297MiB / 24576MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A     43004      C   python3                         12295MiB |
|    3   N/A  N/A     40093      C   python3                         12295MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Not sure what video card you have, but I am assuming this is in a server?  Mine does the same thing in my server and it is a more of on demand thing.  I run a Plex Server that can use the GPUs, and it does, but a lot of it is dependent on the way the video is encoded and what is needed to process it.  Other than that, mine will usually sit at 0% utilization.